# What determines your camp's tier?

Tags: goblin-camp

Recently, I've been having trouble with my camps advancing very far, mainly because I can't get stone. (When I remember to plant stuff, and I don't attack a unicorn.) I think that getting to the "Camp" tier, it takes a farm and saw pit, but what about the third tier? Is there a fourth? I've made it to the third tier on v1.3, but can't in the newest version (1.41) even after building every workshop.

Comment: And of course, immediately after this gets answered I finally find the wiki page on Tiers that I have been looking for for so long. http://goblincampwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the requirements to tier up are: population, number of workshops and production (a rating based on the number of things created in workshops). You also need at least one farm.

The requirements for the different tiers is:

Tier 1 (Camp)

2 workshops, population 20-29, and production > 20

Tier 2 (Settlement)

6 workshops, population 30-39, and production > 100

Tier 3

11 workshops, population 40-59, and production > 500

Tier 4

Population 60-99, and production > 1000

Tier 5

Population 100-199, and production > 3000

Tier 6

Population 200+ and production > 10000

There is a bug in the current version (1.41) that if your population exceeds the range of the next tier before you meet the other requirements, you won't progress to the next tier - so if you are at tier 1 and have population 40 before having enough workshops or production then you can't progress to tier 2 but need to skip straight to tier 3 (or cull your population).